# Git push different branches to different remote repos?

Tags: git, github

How can I push two branches of the same project to different repos on github?

I have two branches locally:

- master
- develop

On **master** I have a "coming soon" page that deploys to Github pages and in the meanwhile I work on **develop** locally.

But now I want to have a preview of "develop" on a different GitHub page, so i thought the best way of doing so would be to push only that branch to a different repo. Is that possible?

Thanks,

Matteo

Comment: If the `master` and `develop` branches are logically related/connected, then why are you considering using two different repos to store them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can push and fetch anything you want anywhere you've got the access.  Just do it: add a remote for the other repo, call it "preview" or something, and `git push preview develop`.  If you also want that history in the original, push it there too.

Comment: Aha! that was easier than expected. Now the thing is that I have the "preview" local branch on the "preview" remote branch of the "preview" repo. But on GitHub Pages I can only deploy the master branch of that repo... can i push the "preview" local branch on the remote "master" branch?

Thanks!

Comment: ok i was being lazy... found the solution on github documentation [here] (https://help.github.com/en/articles/pushing-to-a-remote). 

I just did git push preview develop:master

Answer (score -2):

I don't think you can push one branch to separate repo. You can do either of these things.

1. Either you create a separate project for develop branch and push to a new repo
2. Or You can push master to Repo1, then change remote of your project using

   git remote set-url origin new_url

then push your develop, **But this will also push your master - You will have to separately remove that**

3. IF both the branches are linked, I don't think you need a separate Git repo